# Pushwoosh - Broadcast push notifications

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, push, pushwoosh

We're having a small issue when sending broadcast push notifications
to all ios devices, for some reason, only iPads are receiving the
notifications.

We are using the 'Send Push' section of the admin panel to do this, we
haven't configured anything specifically. Additionally, the app is a
'for iphone' app, so the ipads are running the same app as the iphone
versions.

All devices are receiving custom notifications when sent via the rest
service, the issue only occurs when using the site admin panel.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Bav

Answer (score -2):

Did you tried StreetHawk? It pushes to iPhone/iPad, and Android as well. It has self-defined push type, meanwhile support your own customized json push. Check http://streethawk.com/.